# Spring Boot "Ignored because not a concrete top-level class"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this (https://github.com/Danix43/HerculesAPI) REST application made by Java with Spring Boot.

All good when for some reason the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation doesn't find anymore the interfaces `TermometruService` annothed with `@Service`.

I have tried everything from using `@ComponentScan` with the service package but then any Rest operation returns a `RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND` to changing the jdk version and a flush of maven repositories.

[Project structure if useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCRqF.png)

[The log after running the application](https://pastebin.com/QFvfCNvJ)

```
2020-01-27 19:33:39.635 DEBUG 6248 --- [main] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: file [D:\Programe\Programare\Java\HerculesAPI\target\classes\com\herculesapi\services\TermometruService.class]
```

Comment: use @EntityScan

Comment: Does the github code you provided contains updated code ? If yes then i don't see @service over the service interface..

Comment: There is no @Service annotation on TermometruServiceImpl. I expect that you already tried that and it still doesn't work?

Comment: The Github code is pretty incomplete (There is no @Service on TermometruService)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by annotating the TermometruServiceImple class with @Service. Also regarding the Github repository, it doesn't always have all the changes right away pushed but yes the TermometruService interface had the annotation.